# Strange crash of the visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, crash

I've accidentally broken visual studio:

I have two different versions: VS express and ultimate.

I installed an add-on a month ago, and were working for some project.
Now I working for same project almost two weeks, and it's now acting strange.

After some writing I tried to debug it, it was successfully built, but after launch VS crashed.

Here is a list of things I've tried:

1. Safe mode - works
2. Reseting to default - not work
3. Reinstalling - not work
4. Try in express - works

Google doesn't help me. I'm writing an c# console app and I don't have any idea what the problem is.

If anyone knows where is the problem or has experienced something similar, please help me (:

P.S. Sorry my bad english

Comment: The problem seems to come from the add-on. Did you try uninstalling it?

Comment: What error message(s) are you getting? And what add-on did you install?

Comment: 1. It was working perfectly all time.  2. I already reinstall the whole VS, and it's doesn't work, only in safe mode

Comment: What was the add-on? Was it a time limited demo?

Comment: It was propower tools, hidemenu and thememanagerpackage. It all was the full versions, as VS is.

Comment: That's weird. After run devenv /log on starting then appears some errors about achivments addon, and then crushes are dissapear. I will try to uninstall it, and than see what append

Answer (score 2):

If safe mode works then I'd say its probably the addon's fault... I'd remove the addon.

Comment: Problem was with achivments extensions. When the add tryes to generate achivement by going to one of the lines, it makes the addon crushes all VS. and i learned that addons not deleting by deliting the VS studio. Thanks for all, who tryed to help (:

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with achivments extensions. When the add tryes to generate achivement by going to one of the lines, it makes the addon crushes all VS. and i learned that addons not deleting by deliting the VS studio. Thanks for all, who tryed to help (: